# How do I use multiple encodings when running an ant build?

Tags: java, encoding, ant

I have three files in my project that have `iso-8859-1` encoded text. When I try to run my Ant build script I get "unmappable character for encoding UTF8".

However, if I set `-Dfile.encoding=iso8859-1` then it will compile (but obviously I'm not treating it as UTF8).

How can I specify that these three files should be treated as `iso-8859-1` and the rest of them should be treated as UTF-8?

Comment: And how do you "treat" them exactly?

Comment: @fge i don't understand your question

Comment: Well, what do you do with them?

Comment: The files? I want java to compile them. But they contain characters that are invalid utf. Everything else in the project is utf